# Is it possible to target IE10 in Windows 8 Mode in CSS or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, windows-8, internet-explorer-10, conditional-comments

I have noticed that there are some rendering differences with IE10 when it is running in Windows 8 mode vs. Desktop mode related to sizing using Viewport Units.

In a nutshell, it appears that a vw unit is interpreted as approximately twice the size in Win 8 mode than it is in Desktop mode in IE10.

Are there any known ways to target the browser in Win8 mode?

Any new conditional comments?

Can't find any reference to this.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this will help:

```
<script>
if(window.Windows){
 document.documentElement.setAttribute("metro", true);
}
</script>
<style>
         body { color: blue; }
 [metro] body { color: red; }
</style>
```